# What is a better solution to have a duplicate site with some different content?

Tags: html, iframe, seo

My client has got a corporate site and some dealer sites. He would like to have his dealer sites pretty much the same as the corporate site except having different contact information and a different team member page. Here is the question, is there a way that if he updates the corporate site, it updates all the dealer sites as well? Because the content is the same, he does not want to login to every site, copy and paste the content again and again. Any suggestions? I thought about using iframe, but is it good for seo if 95% of the site is iframe?

Comment: 1. iframes are not good for SEO 2. Duplicate content is also not good for SEO.

Comment: You can also do the redirection for all the pages except for those that are different from the original site. But ideally you should have it all on the same webpage with different landing pages for different dealer links

Comment: We should need some precisions to be able to post an accurate answer. When you say "he updates", you mean files or content (ie database) ? What are the exact differences between corporate and dealer sites ? Some pages changes ? Html structure or only data displayed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method you could use is a singular CMS service that houses all the content for all the sites.

Once the user browses to the site you can provide a host header look up to determine which dealer site (or corporate) the user is browsing to. From this information it should be relatively easy to load different contact information.

As you haven't provided many other details such as web server, programming language we can really only help you with theoretical answers.

Hope this helps.